# Is there an easy way to find out which data changed (i.e., caused an update in the lifecycle) in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, lifecycle

In Vue, [watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) provide the old value as well as the new value for a specific property.

Is something similar possible in [lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram) such as `beforeUpdate` or `updated`?

I would just like to be able to determine the root cause for updates without having to add a watcher to every single property in my data.

Comment: As you can see, the hooks don't receive args, so there's no way to know this, at least with official ways. Consider explaining your case if you have a specific one. Could be watchers or something else. FWIW, with pinia you get fine-grained control over store updates